# Google Cloud Storage Delete file in a specific path Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to use Google Cloud Storage node.js (or Firebase Storage admin) to delete a specific file in a specific directory. Here is my attempt:

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: projectId,
  keyFilename: 'serviceAccountKey.json'
});
const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket");
const file = bucket.file('path1/path2/filename');
file.delete().then(function(data) {
  const apiResponse = data[0];
  console.log(apiResponse);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Because my file is located in the path `bucket/path1/path2/filename`, it is not directly located inside the bucket. But when I run the codes, it produces an error:

```
    {
      message: 'No such object: bucket/path1/path2/filename',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'notFound'
    }
```

I have also tried

```
const bucket = storage.bucket("bucket/path1/path2/");
const file = bucket.file('filename');
```

It failed with the same error.

I did take a look at the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#delete). It did not mention anything about delete a file at a specific directory. In that case, how do I delete a specific file at a specific directory in my Google Cloud Storage with node.js then?

Comment: A bucket is a container of objects.  Each object in a bucket has a name.  Directories are in illusion in GCS ... there are only objects.  An object that ends with "/" in its name is logically considered a directory.  If you use the GCS browser, what does the name of the object show up as.  I think you may be trying to find an object in a bucket and adding the bucket name in object name when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

make sure that:

1- you are passing the correct bucket name

2- the full name of the file starting from it's first directory and it should be something like "read/test.txt"

3- the file indeed exists because you may have deleted and then tried again and this case the file won't exist

You may try also this code example:

```
function main(bucketName, filename) {
  
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  
    // Creates a client
    const storage = new Storage();
  
    async function deleteFile() {
      // Deletes the file from the bucket
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename).delete();
  
      console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
    }
  
    deleteFile().catch(console.error);
    // [END storage_delete_file]
  }

  main("my-bucket", "read/test.txt")
```

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try.

Comment: What if I'm trying to delete an entire folder? I tried doing something like your answer but it did not seem to work for me. I also tried 
    `await bucket.deleteFiles({prefix: 'folder/'})`